# selenium webdriver : sendkeys is not entirely send, it resets the text

Tags: java, maven, selenium, webdriver, sendkeys

I am doing a sendkeys on an element of input type but when I watch the navigator it writes for example "And", it erases, it writes "ré M", it erases, and it writes again "uzin" instead of just writting "André Muzin". 
So my test is failed.

Here the code to find the element :

```
@FindBy(how = How.CSS, using = "input[data-automation-id='searchBox']")
       public WebElement TB_MENTOR2;
```

Here the method which is calling it :

```
public void AddMentor(String functionality, String mentorName, String mentorType, String comment){
         System.out.println(" ----- Going to the Mentor Page");
         TB_SEARCH.sendKeys(functionality);
         TB_SEARCH.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
         TB_GOTO_ADDMENT.click();
         TB_MENTOR1.click();
         TB_MENTOR2.sendKeys(mentorName);
         ...
}
```

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Please post a link or respective HTML code.

Comment: It is confidential ! But I finally found a solution :D

Answer (score 0):

The webpage make a reset. And Selenium is typing really fast !
That's why I needed to wait 2s before sendKeys, to wait the reset.

Comment: If there is something you can wait for that indicates the page is done loading and won't reset that field on you, that would be safer and make your tests go faster. The more sleeps you have, the quicker your tests become monstrously unmaintainable, because you'll have a bunch of random failures that are difficult to reproduce.